# Install app for SharePoint using PowerShell - permissions on user profiles

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin, powershell

I'm trying to install our app using the PowerShell and after running the application I get an error while accessing the user profile data. We are using the following permissions in our app:

```
AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read"
AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl"
```

This is the part of the PowerShell where I set up the permissions:

```
Register-SPAppPrincipal -DisplayName $appName -NameIdentifier $appIdentifier -Site $web 
$principal =  Get-SPAppPrincipal -Site $siteCollection -NameIdentifier $appIdentifier
Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission -Site $siteCollection -AppPrincipal $principal -Scope SiteSubscription -Right FullControl
```

If the app is installed from SharePoint it works perfectly, therefore I think the problem lays in the app permissions.

Comment: You have to give User profile read permission.

Comment: Well apparently yes, but how do I do this using PowerShell?

Comment: I think powershell command is not available for that. You can only set app permissions for site,Site collection,Site subscription.Check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219714(v=office.15).aspx. You will have to edit app manifest and add it

Comment: Well it is in the app manifest.

AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" 

Now I need to find the way to add it via PowerShell.